# Python 2.7 _ adding to string deletes string?

Tags: python, string

newby/hobbycoder here.

I wrote a script which runs through a .M3U files and downloads all referenced  media. (previews for my record store).

now i manage to get the correct path from the download function this exact way, but for some weird reason the following loop just returns ".mp3"

```
#write id3 tags

i = 1

for file in os.listdir("/Users/username/Desktop/transmisson"):
    artist = str(nucontainer[i][2].replace("/", ""))
    track = str(nucontainer[i][1].replace("/",""))
    album = str(nucontainer[i][3].replace("/", ""))
    filetype = ".mp3"

    fullfilename = "/Users/username/Desktop/transmisson/" 
    + artist + " - " + track + " - " + album + filetype
```

## EDIT

artist, track, album, filetype all return the correct string
if i concatenate them, they return what i expect

as soon as i add ".mp3" it al goes pear shaped

## EDIT

this gives the same problem.

## write id3 tags

```
i = 0

while i < len(nucontainer):
    artist = nucontainer[i][2].replace("/", "")
    track = nucontainer[i][1].replace("/","")
    album = nucontainer[i][3].replace("/", "")
    filename = artist + " - " + track + " - " + album + ".mp3"
    print filename
    i += 1
```

Comment: What do you expect `os.path.join('/Users/username/Desktop/transmisson/' 
    + artist + " - " + track + " - " + album + filetype)` to produce as result exactly?

Comment: a string with the path name

Comment: Yeah, then it's not doing what you expect it to do. See Sam's answer

Comment: os.path.join shouldnt have been there - it was an experiment trying to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: Also, why the `str()` around `nucontainer[i][...].replace("/", "")`? `replace` is already a method of `string`, so I'm assuming `nucontainer[i][2]` is a string, in which case `str()` is redundant

Comment: reduntant, yes, however it's another thing i tried to figure out whats wrong

Comment: What is `nucontainer`? And are you really sure that `nucontainer[[1]][2]` is a string? Accessing an element in `nucontainer` with the list `[1]` as an index seems funny.

Comment: nucontainer is a list of lists and i am accessing index i ... dunno whats funny about this. and yes, I am sure it's a string, Please read the post i edited

Comment: See my edit below, based on your comment of `nucontainer` being a list of lists.

Comment: If `i` is `[1]` then you don't access `nucontainer[1][2]` but `nucontainer[[1]][2]` (see the additional brackets).

Comment: have you tried `fullfilename = "/Users/username/Desktop/transmisson/" 
    + artist + " - " + track + " - " + album + ".mp3"`?

Comment: yep, same result :/

Answer (score 0):

Separate the paths in `os.path.join` with commas.

```
filename = artist + " - " + track + " - " + album + filetype
fullfilename = os.path.join('/Users/username/Desktop/transmisson/', filename)
```

Comment: fullfilename = os.path.join('/Users/username/Desktop/transmisson/', artist, " - ", track, " - ", album, filetype) will return "/.mp3"

Comment: if i create the variable first and use your exact example it will return "/Users/username/Desktop/transmisson/
.mp3"

Comment: But is the variable `filename` correct before you concatenate with the path '/Users/username/Desktop/transmisson/'?

Comment: yes, thats the headf***k. and all the list entries are strings

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that you don't 'return' or store anything. Right now, it just loops through the whole directory. Don't you want to store all the fullfilename data or something?

Edit: You don't seem to actualy do something wih `file` in the loop. Right now you are only referencing `i`, but `i` is not defined in your code.

Edit2: Based on your comment that nucontainer is a list of lists, I would assume that you should do something like this:

```
for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir("/Users/username/Desktop/transmisson")):
    artist = str(nucontainer[i][2].replace("/", ""))
    track = str(nucontainer[i][1].replace("/",""))
    album = str(nucontainer[i][3].replace("/", ""))
    filetype = ".mp3"

    fullfilename = "/Users/username/Desktop/transmisson/" 
    + artist + " - " + track + " - " + album + filetype
```

Comment: correct - I want to eventually use each run in the loop to change the id3 tag. but i am not getting past creating the file path here. in your example - if i print fullfilename the result is ".mp3"

Comment: But still I don't see anything happening with `file` in your for-loop. Right now, your code should give you the exact same output for 'artist',track, etc. for every loop.

Comment: I don't see the relevance to the question though. I am simply interested in knowing why adding multiple strings together ends up deleting the string when adding ".mp3"

Comment: Well, concatenating, or 'adding' to a string doesn't delete it. So somehow, something else is going wrong in your code. Just trying to help here to find the problem....

Comment: i get it, didn mean to sound rude. fyi i get the same issue if i replace for with a while i < len(nucontainer).